# Pass selected option value to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html select that is filled with data from the database.
It looks like this

```
echo '<select name="client_list">';

  foreach ($htmlselect as $key => $row) {
  echo 
  '<option value='.$row->CUSTOMERCODE.'>'
  .$row->CUSTOMERNAME. '</option>';
  }
 echo '</select>';
```

Below it I have a table that is populated with values from the DB.

```
$table = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT STRING, DATE, STRING02  FROM `CUSTOMERFILE` WHERE `code` = 2 AND `status` = 2');

        echo  '<thead ><tr >';
        foreach ($header as $list) {
            echo '<th >' . $list . '</th>';
        }
        echo "<thead></tr>";
  if ( !empty( $table) ) {

             foreach ( $table as $key => $value  ) {
           echo '<tr >';
             foreach ( $value as $a ) {
                if (empty($a)) {
                    # code...
                    echo '<td>NULL</td>';
                } else {
                      echo '<td>' . $a . '</td>';
                      }
                 }   
            echo '</tr>';
          }
      }
```

Now in this query I want to add to the where another condition that takes the selected option value from the html select

It would look something like this

```
$table = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT STRING, DATE, STRING02  FROM `CUSTOMERFILE` WHERE `code` = 2 AND `status` = 2 **AND STRING05 = selected option value**');
```

How do I pass the selected value in the query?

Comment: Do you have a variable containing the selected option? How are you storing the current option? Or is this after a form submission?

Comment: I'm not storing the current option anywhere yet. I need to pass it to the query below it in the 'where' condition.

Comment: I tried this $value = $row->CUSTOMERCODE; $CSC = $_POST[$value]; and I get undefined this error: "Undefined offset "optionvalue"

Answer (score 0):

The `$wpdb->get_results()` function take 2 parameters, the first is the query and the second is the output

`$wpdb->get_results($command, $output);`

Comment: The functions works just fine in displaying the table. I need to modify it, to be able to display that which is selected from the html select.

Comment: That's not quite true, the second output determines the format of the results, it doesn't store the results, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Comment: It is optional and the default is an object. Later I display the data from it using foreach loop.